# Object ID conflict in extensions in AL (Business Central OnPremises)

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-dynamics, objectid

I'm a beginner in Dynamics Nav/Dynamics365/Business Central developing extensions in AL and I'm having a problem that I don't know how to solve it 'easily'.

I am working with 2 projects in Visual Studio Code at the same time in one workspace (previously I tried it in multiple workspaces) and there are 2 'pageextension' objects with ID 50100.
I'm having the following error:

**The application object of type 'PageExtension' with the ID '50100' is defined in multiple apps. The apps are: Reports by myName 2.1.0.0; Workspace2 by myName2 1.0.0.0.**

I know this error could be fixed changing the object ID but I think it should exist another solution.
Does this mean that if someone publishes and install an extension and then try to publish and install mine, will BC OnPrem not allow them to work with the second?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The range you describe should only be used for customisations.
When publishing for AppSource, you will get a specific number range for your app.

If you intend to use multiple apps for customisations, you should divide the range and make sure you do not use double id's.